# Ubuntu 18.04.1 desktop live dvd install does not see existing installation

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors

I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 installed on my computer. It recently (after an upgrade) stopped being able to boot up with two monitors. I can't even get to the grub menu.

I can still boot with 1 monitor, and my live 18.04.1 ubuntu dvd boots up fine with both monitors.

However, if I choose 'install', booting with the live dvd, when it gets to the installation type selection (thought I would safely reinstall working graphics over my data), it does not recognize any ubuntu installation on my computer.

What should I do to get my dual monitor system working?

---

```
$ sudo lshw -class video 
*-display description: VGA compatible controller 
product: GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] 
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation 
physical id: 0 
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0 
version: a1 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz 
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom 
configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0 
resources: irq:130 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff –
```

Comment: what is your video card? can you boot with one monitor and run `sudo lshw -class video` and post the results... might be a driver issue

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the latest pro driver from nvidia.

Start by adding the graphics drivers ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Now you can install the nvidia 390 driver:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
```

Then reboot and you should be good to go.

IF you want to try the newest driver (not recommended, see below):

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-396
```

NOTE: This driver (v396) breaks my system and X won't load. If you end up with not being able to get X to start, purge the NVIDIA drivers, and install a different version instead. To purge your nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
```

And then install a different version per above instructions.